# Как собрать проект Java swing?

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. У меня есть исходный код Цезаря. Но при компиляции у меня пустая форма. Подскажите, как исправить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 public class CesarAthens extends javax.swing.JFrame {  
String message, alphabet = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя.,_!";  
int key = 0;  
public CesarAthens() {  
    initComponents();  
}  
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  
    message = jTextPane1.getText();  
    message = formatText(message, alphabet);  
    key = (int) jSpinner1.getValue();  
    CryptMessage(message, key, alphabet);  
}  
private String formatText(String text, String alphabet) {  

    text = text.toLowerCase();  

    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(text);  
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {  
        if (message.charAt(i) == ' ') {  
            message.deleteCharAt(i);  
        }  
    }  

    StringBuilder alpBuilder = new StringBuilder(alphabet);  
    text = "";  
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {  
        for (int j = 0; j < alpBuilder.length(); j++) {  
            char c = message.charAt(i);  
            if (c == alpBuilder.charAt(j)) {  
                text += c;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    return text;  
}  
void CryptMessage(String message, int key, String alphabet){  
    StringBuilder messagetwo = new StringBuilder(message);  
    StringBuilder alpBuilder = new StringBuilder(alphabet);  
    message = "";  
    for (int i = 0; i<messagetwo.length();i++){  
        for (int j = 0; j < alpBuilder.length(); j++) {  
            char c = messagetwo.charAt(i);  
            if (c == alpBuilder.charAt(j)) {  
                int a = j+key;  
                while (a >= alpBuilder.length()) {  
                    a -= alpBuilder.length();  
                }  
                message += alpBuilder.charAt(a);  
            }  
        }  
    }  
    jTextPane2.setText(message);  
}  
public static void main(String args[]) {  
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
        public void run() {  
            new CesarAthens().setVisible(true);  
        }  
    });  
}  
// Variables declaration - do not modify  
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;  
private javax.swing.JFileChooser jFileChooser1;  
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;  
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;  
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;  
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;  
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;  
private javax.swing.JSpinner jSpinner1;  
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane1;  
private javax.swing.JTextPane jTextPane2;  
// End of variables declaration  

private void initComponents() {
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

Comment: Обычно в initComponents происходит размещение компонентов на форме. У Вас по каким-то причинам initComponents пустой (не считая комментария). Вот и окошко получается пустым, никто туда ничего не положил.